# Taurus: Play a scenario every 5 minutes

Tags: performance-testing, blazemeter, taurus

I have an authenticate scenario which return a token. After 5 minutes (example), the token is expired. But this token is mandatory for the success of other scenarios.
Now, I don't really want to run this scenario each time before the other scenarios. 
Ideally, I will run it a first time, get the token, and when the expiration time, rerun the authenticate scenario.

Currently, my yml file follow this logic:

```
execution:
- scenario: mainload

scenarios:
  authenticate:
    requests:
      - http://auth.com
  mainload:
    requests:
      - include-scenario: http://needToken.com
      - http://needToken.com
```

So, how can I using Taurus inside an yml file do this? Like, waiting 5 minutes before relaunching the scenario?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 `scenario` elements, one for authentication and another one for main load, the relevant Taurus YAML syntax would be something like:

```
execution:
- scenario: authenticate
- scenario: mainload

scenarios:
  authenticate:
    think-time: 5m
    requests:
      - http://example.com
  mainload:
    requests:
      - http://blazedemo.com
```

The `think-time` attribute basically adds a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) with 5 minutes "sleep" time so the request to `example.com` will be executed each 5 minutes while others will be fired without delays.

References:

- [Building Test Plan from Config](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config)
- [Taurus Configuration Syntax](http://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/)
- [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)

Comment: I added more information inside my question. I use `include-scenario` to extract the token from the response and i use it inside the following scenario